# Can't delete Database item SQLite Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I've been going round in circles with this for days and I can't get my head around what's wrong.
With the following code, when you press the "yes" button to delete the item you touched, it shows everything and appears to do everything but the item is not removed from the list.

Activity class:

```
package com1032.em00224.knit;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NoteActivity extends Activity {

  private ListView list;    
   DatabaseHandler db;
   int id_To_Update = 0;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_note);

      db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
      ArrayList array_list = db.getAllNotes();

  ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter =      
  new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);

  //adding it to the list view.
  list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

  list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, final int position,
 long arg3) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(NoteActivity.this); 
     adb.setTitle("Delete Note?");
     adb.setMessage(R.string.deleteNote); 
     adb.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
             db.deleteNote(position + 1);
             arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Note Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com1032.em00224.knit.NoteActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
         }
     });
     adb.setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
         }
     }); 
     adb.show();
 }
 }); 
 }
```

And the Database helper:

```
package com1032.em00224.knit;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "NoteDatabase.db";
   public static final String NOTES_TABLE_NAME = "notes";
   public static final String NOTES_COLUMN_ID = "id";
   public static final String NOTES_COLUMN_NOTE = "note";

   public DatabaseHandler(Context context)
   {
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      db.execSQL(
      "create table notes " +
      "(id integer primary key, note text)"
     );
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
      onCreate(db);
  }

   public boolean insertNote  (String note)
 {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put("note", note);

    db.insert("notes", null, contentValues);
    return true;
 }
   public Cursor getData(int id){
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts where id="+id+"", null );
     return res;
 }
 public int numberOfRows(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, NOTES_TABLE_NAME);
    return numRows;
 }
  public boolean updateNote (Integer id, String note)
  {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("note", note);
    db.update("notes", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) }     );
    return true;
 }

   public Integer deleteNote (Integer id)
 {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  return db.delete("notes", 
  "id = ? ", 
  new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
 }

 public ArrayList getAllNotes()
 {
  ArrayList array_list = new ArrayList();
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from notes", null );
  res.moveToFirst();
  while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
  array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(NOTES_COLUMN_NOTE)));
  res.moveToNext();
  }
 return array_list;
 }
 }
```

Everything else, such as adding a new item, works as it should.

Edit - It now deletes the one that is selected, but it doesn't always actually delete and there seems to be no pattern - I've added some `system.out.printlns` to get a clearer picture but it says that it is deleting the right one when it isn't.

Comment: But where you called `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. After delete item you must called `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: @SimplePlan I have added this but it still doesn't remove the item, do I put this after db.delete(position)?

Comment: please search for some good DatabaseHandler  class in google, and this hard coded working is not a good practice.To find the issue debug the app and  search inside deleteNote for what is happening

Comment: Did you refresh your `ListView` with 'adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged`? And did you actually see item is removed from the database?Try log the database.

Comment: Maybe you should try looking into some common design patterns, the observer pattern could work a treat for you here!

Answer (score 0):

In some Projects I faced the same Problem. So there are two possible Solutions. First, after removing Your data from database, also remove item from listview/Adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged:

```
   db.deleteNote(position);
   arrayAdapter.remove(arrayAdapter.getItem(itemToRemove));
   arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So, my Problem was, that this sometimes doesn´t work, until now, I don´t know what I was doing wrong. Anyway, if this doesn´t work, refresh the whole data after deleting:

```
    private void refreshData(){

           ArrayList array_list = db.getAllNotes();
           ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter =      
            new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);
            list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            list.invalidateViews();

     }
```

So this should look somehting like this in Your onClick:

```
     adb.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
         db.deleteNote(position);
         refreshData();
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Note Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  com1032.em00224.knit.NoteActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
     }
  });
```

This is just from scratch, I can´t test the code for now because I have no IDE here. So don´t forget to do some Workaround (like opening and closing database etc.).

Comment: This is very helpful! I tried the refresh data way first, but that doesn't work - maybe there is something wrong with the delete method? For the other way, how would i put the selected item in itemToRemove?

Comment: For this, You have to set the listView onItemClickListener and get the item Position integer on click. Try to read the database after You have deleted something, there are some apps for reading db, for example DB Browser. If the note is not deleted, come back to me and we will check what´s going wrong.

Comment: I'm a bit strapped for time and the DB Browser just won't work, so i've changed the method to delete all the items and that works - so it appears to be a problem with finding the id of the selected item - i don't know if you could help with that?

Comment: ok i will try...what about deleting with: db.delete(NOTES_TABLE_NAME, NOTES_COLUMN_ID +  "=" + id, null) > 0; . And by the way, all other methods inside Your db work? Insert and update?

Comment: That way only seems to delete certain items, and definitely not the one I clicked. I tried without the > 0 and that doesn't do anything

Comment: could You Show me, what exactly is displayed in the list? Can You make a screenshot and Show it in Your question?

Comment: added some screenshots and a description of what appears to be happening

Comment: ah, ok, I think I know where the Problem is. Also, this was a mistake in my brain, sorry for that :). What You get is the Position integer, but You Need the id. It´s not the same, Position counting starts at 0. So, how is Your listview build? Do You have a textView inside? If yes, get the TextView´s text in Your onItemClick: TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);  String text = textView.getText().toString();  Then, convert String to int and pass it to Your delete.

Comment: What if It is just a simple list view widget with out the textview? how do i get the id of an item?

Comment: then try String text = (TextView)(view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).getText().toString(); this should refer to the listviews item, which is a textView

Comment: unfortunately, this gets the actual text inside the item rather than the id of the item

Comment: yes sure, but if I understand You the right way, the displayed number is the id that is stored inside database, isn´t it? The id of the listview item is not the id inside Your database, so you would have no success to get listview item id...